# Selective rolling join

Tags: r, data.table

Is there a way to select which columns get rolled when you join? I'm trying to build up missing columns, kind of like this:

```
dt <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), c = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), 
r = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 3L), ir1 = c(0.690859583206475, 0.0255513035226613, 
0.381394953466952, 0.646164963953197), ir2 = c(0.869432955048978, 
0.911753778578714, 0.421218475792557, 0.653007542947307)), .Names = c("id", 
"c", "r", "ir1", "ir2"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -4L))

expander <- expand.grid(id = 1:2, c=1:2, r=1:5)

setkey(dt, id, c, r) 
setkey(setDT(expander),id,c,r)
dt[expander, roll = TRUE]
```

Now let's say I only wanted `ir2` to roll, leaving NA values in `ir1`. Is that possible?

I'm trying to avoid using `na.locf()` on a few million rows for a process that's running on an API (every milisecond counts).

Bonus: Commentary on a data.table approach to creating the `expander` object would also be helpful (assuming that it's more like a fixed `data.frame(id,c)` and repetitions of `r`)

Comment: For `expander` you could do `CJ(1:2, 1:2, 1:5)`

Comment: Try that when the first two columns are a fixed data frame. I did a bad job explaining that. Sorry. I tried using cj but imagine it was a data frame in the first position that would work.

Comment: You can do the same in a `data.frame`. Something like `do.call(CJ, data.frame(id = 1:2, c=1:2, r=1:2))`

Comment: Thanks I will try that out.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen `CJ` can easily blown up the processing, you can add input validation, something like `stopifnot(prod(length(v1), length(v2), length(v3)) < 1e7)`, if duplicates occurs then `uniqueN`.

Comment: doing two joins is the only option I can think of - `dt[dt[expander, .(id, c, r, ir1)], roll = T, .(id, c, r, i.ir1, ir2)]`